# Wrong reputation shown on Area51 profile -> accounts page

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, profile-page

When I visit [my Area51 profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/78564?tab=accounts) page and goto `accounts` tab, at the end it shows Tex - Latex account as follows with `1` reputation:

[image]

My actual rep is `101`, which can be seen below and on my [Tex - Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/60948/shobhit-puri) profile as well. I joined on 19th August 2014. Is this a small bug or some script didn't run?

[image]

Comment: Showing 101 to me [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/78564?tab=accounts), you still see 1?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Now it seems fine for me. Its uneven. See [AsheeshR](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/70968?tab=accounts)'s `Area51` `profile` -> `accounts` now. For him its showing `1` rep for the last `Ask Different`. However his real [rep on Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/72397/asheeshr) is `101`.

Comment: It seems after visiting its link from the profile, it updates in some time to the real one. Not sure what it is but I can only give snapshots.

Comment: I've seen this too at times, but it seems to be ND.  I don't think caching is the answer because we're talking about sites where the rep has *never* been 1.