# How often is the Area 51 user flair updated?

Tags: support, area-51

How often is the [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History) user [flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/flair/info) updated?

It doesn't seem to update, as seen here:

[image: Screenshot of flair]

Because that is really outdated! Also, the accounts list doesn't update:

[image: Screenshot of a Stack Exchange accounts list]

Or is there some way that we update it ourself?

Comment: related/dup? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255919/area51-user-flair-not-updating , https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52119/why-doesnt-an-associated-account-appear-in-my-flair-on-area51 , https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252987/rep-flair-incorrect , https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238516/users-account-lists-on-area51-are-incomplete , https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244302/wrong-reputation-shown-on-area51-profile-accounts-page

Answer (score 3):

I know how you feel.

It might take about 10 minutes to 2 and a half months. This happened to me and apparently, I also asked a question about [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252987/rep-flair-incorrect) (it's related). Usually it depends how fast caching is at the time. Sometimes it takes a little while and sometimes it takes forever.

Comment: caching? really? _runs to window and shouts!_